# Magic Hexagon can't constrain itself

Tags: list, prolog, logic, constraints, clpfd

I am trying to solve the [Magic Hexagon](http://www.csplib.org/Problems/prob023/) problem in Prolog, in dimension 5, for now(?). I first create the layout, by using a 2D list. Then I try to constraint every element of that list (which is actually a list).
However, I can't make it work, here is my code, *after all the updates*:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

solve(Dim) :-
    length(L, 5), % define 5 diagonals
    Offset is Dim - 2,
    Flag is 0,
    fill(L, Offset, Dim, Flag),
    writeln(L),
    constraint_sum(L, 38),
    writeln(L).
    
constraint_sum([], _).
constraint_sum([H|T], Sum) :-
    label(H),
    sum_list(H, Sum),
    constraint_sum(T, Sum).
    
fill([], _, _, _).
fill([H|T], Len, Dim, Flag) :-
    Flag == 0,
    Len < Dim,
    length(H, Len),
    H ins 1..19,
    all_different(H),
    NewLen is Len + 1,
    fill(T, NewLen, Dim, Flag).
fill([H|T], Len, Dim, _) :-
    length(H, Len),
    H ins 1..19,
    all_different(H),
    NewLen is Len - 1,
    Flag is 1,
    fill(T, NewLen, Dim, Flag).
```

and I am getting:

> 1 ?- solve(5).
>
> [[_G2537,_G2581,_G2617],[_G2857,_G2893,_G2929,_G2965],
>
> [_G3263,_G3299,_G3335,_G3371,_G3407],[_G3757,_G3793,_G3829,_G3865],
>
> [_G4157,_G4193,_G4229]]
>
> [[1,18,19],[1,2,16,19],[1,2,3,13,19],[1,2,16,19],[1,18,19]]
>
> true .

..as you can see the problem is that the elements are not unique, since I have used `all_different()` for every list separately and not for the whole list, but I do not know how do that!

Comment: `sum_list` internally uses `is/2`. So you must have some list elements in the first argument to `sum_list` that aren't instantiated. Your `constraint_sum([H|T], Sum)` looks odd, too. Shouldn't the recursive call be `constraint_sum(T, Sum)` not `sum_list(T, Sum)`? And you're using `Sum` twice which means it will likely fail since `sum_list(H, Sum)` will instantiate `Sum`, and it won't likely match the recursive call to get `Sum`.

Comment: But no element is initialized, if that's what you mean by instantiated @lurker. Well the problem I see so far is that all elements should be different and with my implementation I make all elements of every list to be different with the ones of the same list and not with all the others, as it should.

Comment: See my updated comment. When using `clpfd` you have to call `labeling(Vars)` before doing something like `sum_list` to instantiate the values. So `labeling(H), sum_list(H, Sum)`...

Comment: @lurker thanks, I corrected that but still same error. Well Sum has a fixed value to 38, doesn't it? From when calling `constraint_sum()` inside `solve()`.

Comment: Please finish reading my comments about `sum_list`. :)

Comment: I did @lurker, but `labeling()` in SWI-Prolog requires two arguments, so I am trying to figure out how to call it: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clpfd%3Alabeling/2 I tried something but it failed. Maybe it's because I didn't set the constraint of all elements being unique correct, and I limited it in every list.

Comment: `labeling` does not require two arguments. See [this manual page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=labeling/1).

Comment: @lurker, that was my first go, but: `Warning: The predicates below are not defined. If these are defined Warning: at runtime using assert/1, use :- dynamic Name/Arity. Warning: Warning: labeling/1, which is referenced by Warning: c:/users/samaras/documents/prolog/advanced_ai/mhex.pl:16:8: 2-nd clause of constraint_sum/2`.............However, label() seems to do the trick! Still working on that, updated my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my bet - but I think there is a bug, since the problem page states there is only a solution.

```
:- module(magic_exagon, [magic_exagon/0]).
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

magic_exagon :-
    magic_exagon(3, 38).

magic_exagon(N, Sum) :-
    R is N*2-1,
    findall(L, (between(1,R,C), c_cells(C,N,R,L)), Rows),
    flatten(Rows, Cells),
    length(Cells, Max),
    Cells ins 1..Max,
    all_different(Cells),

    get_diags(Rows, N,R,1, LeftDiags),

    reverse(Rows, Rev),
    maplist(reverse, Rev, RevRows),
    get_diags(RevRows, N,R,1, RightDiags),

    maplist(sum_diags(Sum), Rows),
    maplist(sum_diags(Sum), LeftDiags),
    maplist(sum_diags(Sum), RightDiags),

    label(Cells),
    show(rows, Rows).

c_cells(C,N,R,L) :-
    ( C > N ->   M is N+R-C ; M is N+C-1 ),
    length(L,M).

sum_diags(Sum, Diag) :-
    sum(Diag, #=, Sum).

get_diags([], _,_,_, []).
get_diags(Rows, N,R,C, [Diag|Diags]) :-
    c_cells(C, N, R, Diag),
    capture(Diag, Rows, RestWithEmpty),
    drop_empties(RestWithEmpty, Rest),
    C1 is C+1,
    get_diags(Rest, N,R,C1, Diags).

capture([], Rest, Rest).
capture([Cell|Diag], [[Cell|Cs]|Rows], [Cs|Rest]) :-
    capture(Diag, Rows, Rest).

drop_empties([[]|RestT], Rest) :- !, drop_empties(RestT, Rest).
drop_empties(Rest, Rest).

show(K,Ds) :- writeln(K), maplist(writeln, Ds).
```

get_diags/5 is tricky to do with indexing. I devised an algorithm to capture a diag from the playground. We cannot use findall/3 after variables have been attributed, hence the recursive loop.

*edit*

To display diagonals, an easy way

```
...
label(Cells),
show(rows, Rows),
show(left, LeftDiags),
show(right, RightDiags).
```

and we get

```
?- magic_exagon.
rows
[3,16,19]
[17,6,7,8]
[18,4,1,5,10]
[12,2,11,13]
[9,14,15]
left
[3,17,18]
[16,6,4,12]
[19,7,1,2,9]
[8,5,11,14]
[10,13,15]
right
[15,13,10]
[14,11,5,8]
[9,2,1,7,19]
[12,4,6,16]
[18,17,3]
```

Comment: +1 for giving me the `label()` predicate. Your answer seems...logic ( :) ), but I would like to expand on my code!

Comment: @gsamaras: thanks. I failed to grasp where you attempted the difficult part: getting diagonals. So, to better understand the problem, I crafted my solution. HTH

Comment: Thanks..After reading more carefully your answer, I think it answers my new question...Hmm..

Comment: `drop_emtpies(Ls0, Ls)` is: `exclude(=([]), Ls0, Ls)`. I also recommend to use `append/2` instead of `flatten/2`. Also, `C1 #= C + 1` and `R #= N*2 - 1` would look so much nicer!

Comment: @mat: thanks for the suggestions. drop_emtpies/2 with exclude/3 indeed looks much better. I used is/2 on purpose, since - I think - could help gsamaras to distinguish *where* constraints are used.

Comment: And it did, `flatten()` was the key! As a gift I will upvote another answer of yours I like!

Comment: About the bug, well, the first solution that pops-up doesn't seem to be true for the diagonal sum of `B+E+I+M`, I *think*.