# Output |... confuses me

Tags: list, prolog, geometry

EDIT: What I need is a flag to denote when I am below the center.

I am trying to get this [shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33948281/2411320), but I fail to fill the last level correctly!

My latest code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

solve(L, Dim) :-
    length(L, 5), % define 5 diagonals
    Fill is Dim - 2,
    Below_center is 0,
    init_sublists(L, Dim, Fill, Below_center).

init_sublists([], _, _, _).
init_sublists([H|T], Dim, Fill, Below_center) :-
    Below_center == 0,
    length(H, Dim),
    writeln("hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"+Fill),
    init_zeroes(H, Fill),
    NewFill is Fill + 1,
    NewFill =< Dim,
    init_sublists(T, Dim, NewFill, Below_center).
init_sublists([H|T], Dim, Fill, _) :-
    length(H, Dim),
    writeln("ekeiiiiiiiiiiii"+Fill),
    init_zeroes(H, Fill),
    NewFill is Fill - 1,
    NewFill > Dim - 3,
    Below_center is 1,
    init_sublists(T, Dim, NewFill, Below_center).

init_zeroes([], _).
init_zeroes([H|T], Fill) :-
    writeln("edw"+Fill),
    Fill == 0,
    H is 0,
    init_zeroes(T, Fill).
init_zeroes([H|T], Fill) :-
    writeln("edw1"+Fill),
    NewFill is Fill - 1,
    init_zeroes(T, NewFill).
```

and the output is too big to fit even in SWI-Prolog..I am getting *false*.

Comment: I avoided to shameless publicize [my first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33883319/874024) to your problem, but you should really try to understand how I **solved** the diagonals 'extraction'. As I said, doing by indexing it's tricky, and IMO filling with 0s isn't going to do your life easier...

Comment: @CapelliC I tried, but I found no luck, that's why I would like to go for another approach and if it hits a deadend, then I can backtrack... ;) However, if you have any idea on how to proceed with my question, I would be really happy to hear!

Comment: my approach exploits the layout you got as a suggestion in the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33948281/874024) - from where you also got the filling by 0s. Since you said your first approach was similar, try better to understand what get_diags/5 does. In particular, try capture/3, and imagine why I was reversing the lists to get the right-to-left diagonals. You didn't commented about your difficulty understanding my approach, so I didn't explained better

Comment: OK @CapelliC I will have another look at eat after dinner. However, I want to know what this output means `[_G382, _G385, _G388, 0|...]`. Do you know? I want to get the whole answer, but I do not know how! Tired to change default (http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html), but no luck! I had to press `w`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a flag to denote when I am bellow the center, so that I don't fall back in the 2nd clause.